# Convert Spring Cloud Stream to use reactive cloud function

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, kotlin-coroutines, spring-cloud-function, spring-reactive

Currently I have Spring Boot application which is something like this.

```
@Component
@EnableBinding(Source::class)
class EmailMessageProducer(private val source: Source) {

    suspend fun send(textMessage: TextMessage) {

        source.output().send(
            MessageBuilder.withPayload(textMessage).setHeader("service", "test").build()
        )
    }
}
```

I would like to use Spring Cloud Function here using reactive pattern.

Furthermore, is my current solution non blocking? I am asking this because this is my first time using Kotlin coroutine in this context.

Java solution works for me as well since I am just trying to understand the concept here.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a reactive Supplier (e.g., `Supplier<Flux>`).

In your case it would look something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SomeApplication {

    @Bean
    public Supplier<Flux<Message<String>>> messageProducer() {
        return () -> Flux.just(MessageBuilder.withPayload(textMessage).setHeader("service", "test").build());
    }
}
```

Provide `spring.cloud.function.definition=messageProducer` property and this is pretty much it.

Obviously the above example produced a finite stream with a single item, but feel free to modify the returned flux. In fact we discuss this in more details [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_suppliers_sources).

Comment: How do I pass `textMessage` here?

Comment: Pass? Pass to where? This is a Supplier - a producer of Messages. . .

Comment: I see what you mean but in my case I am producing message based on parameter given as you see in my example above.

Comment: You can utilise `EmitterProcessor` for that. Please reference [this section](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_foreign_event_driven_sources) for more details.

Comment: I did this 
`private val processor: EmitterProcessor<TextMessage> = EmitterProcessor.create()`
`@Bean
fun supplier(): Supplier<Flux<EmailMessage>> {

    return Supplier { processor }
}`
and later 
`processor.onNext(textMessageBuilder.build())` however I do not see any message in RabbitMQ do I need to add anything in application.yml

Comment: I don't know what does `and later` means in the context of your comment. The example I pointed out is complete and functioning. What you are showing is a fragment of something. Consider pushing your project (bare minimum, just enoughg to repropduce the issue) to GitHub so one of us can take a look.